# Getting rid of white-space for each String element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I am trying to get rid of all whitespace in each element of my array list.

I could loop through each element, get the text and use `.replace(" ","")`

But is there an easier method or approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easier way to do something to each elements in a list than to go through all elements in the list and do something to each element.

Use a `ListIterator` to iterate the list and update the values:

```
ListIterator<String> itr = list.listIterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  itr.set(itr.next().replaceAll("\\s", ""));
}
```

Note that to replace *all* whitespace (not simply `" "`), you need to use a regular expression, as demonstrated here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such better option. One approach with Java 8 would be to `map` the elements of the list and then `collect` the result:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
List<String> al = Arrays.asList("This is a ", "sentence", "\t with some", "\nwhite \n space ");
al.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s", "")).forEach(System.out::println);
List<String> cleaned = al.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\s", "")).collect(toList());
```

Note that the `\\s` in the `replaceAll` function matches for every whitespace (tabs and linebreaks too) -- not only spaces and not on the first. The simple `replace` function replaces only the **first** occurrence of the pattern.

The result of the example would be following:

```
Thisisa
sentence
withsome
whitespace
```